# Column overlapping absolute position image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlapping

I am having an issue with an absolute position image in bootstrap. When the second column is supposed to jump to the next line for smaller screen sizes it simply overlaps the image. This is my code right now:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div id="imgdiv">
        <img id="ximage" src="css/images/x-ray-lat-left.png" width="578" height="715" border="0"/>
        <img id="emptygif" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" width="578" height="715" usemap="#location-map" border="0"/> 
        <img id="overlayr1">&nbsp;</img>  
        <img id="overlayr2">&nbsp;</img>
        <img id="overlayr3">&nbsp;</img>
        <map name="location-map" id="location-map" border="0">
          <area id="r1" shape="rect" coords="250,250,340,370" href="#" alt="Hilum"/>
          <area id="r2" shape="rect" coords="90,150,340,500" href="#" alt="Heart"/>          
          <area id="r3" shape="rect" coords="130,120,460,530" href="#" alt="Righ Lung"/>
        </map>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Information</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="imgdesc" class="panel-body">
          Description de l'image
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

All of the images I have in the first column are positioned something like this:

```
#ximage{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:0;
}
```

In `md` `sm` and `xs` scree sizes, the second column should fall below the first, but because of the absolute positioning of the images, it overlaps them.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4325/ when i try your code in jsfilddle the div which must overlap the image it doesn't do that !

Answer (score 0):

This is not best practice.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/maxlipsky/gm8612e4/3/

You can add helper class (and hide it on large columns):

```
.h20 {
    height: 20px;   
}
```

And use it like separator:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-12">
      <div id="imgdiv">
        <img id="ximage" src="css/images/x-ray-lat-left.png" width="578" height="715" border="0"/>
        <img id="emptygif" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ce/Transparent.gif" width="578" height="715" usemap="#location-map" border="0"/> 
        <map name="location-map" id="location-map" border="0">
          <area id="r1" shape="rect" coords="250,250,340,370" href="#" alt="Hilum"/>
          <area id="r2" shape="rect" coords="90,150,340,500" href="#" alt="Heart"/>          
          <area id="r3" shape="rect" coords="130,120,460,530" href="#" alt="Righ Lung"/>
        </map>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-10">
        <div class="h20 hidden-lg bg-warning"></div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Information</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="imgdesc" class="panel-body">
                Description de l'image
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```